# Авто импорт некорректно работает Visual Studio Code | TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Во время разработки проекта Nodejs столкнулся с проблемой автоматического импорта.
VS Code авто импортирует вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой желаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно исправить это?

Comment: НАПИСАТЬ РАЗРАБОТЧИКАМ ?

Comment: если чо - могу ссылкой поделиться. ©нессы ятакмногоразделал, честно-причестно

Comment: имеется ввиду, если это баг ...